# how can i perform selector after time without AfterDelay ?! (code unside)

Tags: iphone, ios, time, selector, delay

first of all thanks for getting into my questions.
now, i tried a lot of different ways to call some function in my code but the ways i find it works (performselector:withobject:afterdelay) are get into the function immediately and i need the function to make some "if's" after random times.
Well you can see the code in here-

```
-(void)playGame{
    isButtonPressed=NO;

    int minimum=1;
    int maximum=4;
    int randomTime=(arc4random()%(maximum-minimum))+minimum;
    [self performSelector:@selector(ifButtonNotPressed) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomTime];
}

-(void)closingAction{
    NSLog(@"Closing Panel automatic");
    if (randomFrog==1){
        [self performSelector:@selector(animatePanelCloseAction::) withObject:gameImage1_up withObject:gameImage1_down];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(playGame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
}


-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{

    if (sender == gameButton1 && randomFrog==1){
        [self performSelector:@selector(disableAllButtons)];
        score=score+1;
        isButtonPressed=YES;
        [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%d",score]]; 
        [self performSelector:@selector(closingAction)];
    }
}

-(void)ifButtonNotPressed{
    if (isButtonPressed==NO){
        [self performSelector:@selector(closingAction)];  
    }
}
```

as you can see, im trying to check if button was pressed, but its going inside and check it immeditlly and perform it after delay.

how can i call it after real delay ?!

thank you all.
amir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try NSTimer to fix this issue.

```
if(callTimer)
{
   [callTimer invalidate];
   callTimer=nil;
}
 callTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.50 target:self selector:@selector(callFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

with help of this you can call any function at particular time interval. if function call again then it invalidates current timer and create new timer for that.

Dont forgot to invalidate timer after calling function means invalidate timer in particular function.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use NSTimer class for the same.

```
- (void)FireTimer : (NSInteger) afterTimeInterval
{
    if (afterTimeInterval > 0) //afterTimeInterval is in seconds
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: afterTimeInterval
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(ResetListAfterExpiration:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO];
    }
}

- (void)ResetListAfterExpiration: (NSTimer *)timer
{
     // your actions
     … … …

     [timer invalidate]; // must be done to prevent memory leak
}
```

//Now You call the FireTimer method from where ever you want and it will wait for afterTimeInterval seconds and call the method ResetListAfterExpiration. That's your answer.